# Need to add Tags for Cloudwatch log groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

In our Project, there are 1000's of CloudWatch Log groups. I need to add tags for all log groups.
is there a way that I can add tags for all log groups at a time?

Comment: What do you mean by "at a time"? Do you mean all at once? In any case, all at once or once at a time, you need to tag each log group separately because you won't tag all the log groups the same. You can do it by cli as well as on console.

Answer (score 1):

[`tag-log-group`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/tag-log-group.html) allows you to add tag to one log group at a time. There is no batch api that allows you to do it in one go for multiple log groups. If you are using `aws cli` or `sdk`, it should be easy enough to retrieve [describe-log-groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/describe-log-groups.html) and run execute [`tag-log-group`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/tag-log-group.html).